# Origin of the word "Macau"

Tags: etimologia, origem-histórica, origem

Wikipedia suggests that "Macau" is from Chinese:

> Mage (妈阁 "Pavilion of [the goddess] Mazu").

Etymonline seems to suggest it is from the Chinese:

> Ma'ao (妈澳 "Bay of [the goddess] Mazu").

Another possibility would be:

> Magang (妈港 "Harbor of [the goddess] Mazu").

with the nasal -ng being rendered as a nasal vowel -ao.

Any Portuguese sources on which is correct? Would *"-ao"* be likely added a Portuguese suffix to a Chinese root?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds just as a Portuguese assimilation of a foreign word, ie "Ma'ao".

The Portuguese suffix "ao" requires the special character "ã": "ão" (a superlative). I would bet the origin of the name Macau isn't related to a superlative at all.

Besides Mage, Mazu, Ma'ao, also A. Ma and A-ma-kas are names involved in the history of Macau.

Comment: Oi Ana! Bem vinda! Lembro que as respostas preferencialmente devem ser fundamentadas, preferencialmente com referências e etc.

Comment: Ok, serei cuidadosa. Obrigada!

Comment: Does the au in Macau have a nasal pronunciation in Portuguese?

Comment: @ColinZwanziger I'm not a grammar expert, but in Portuguese, the pronunciation of *au* in "Macau" is very similar to *ow* in English's "cow" and "power" (not sure if it's exactly the same, though).

Answer (score 1):

"The Evolution of Spellings of Macau" by Wu and Jin has an extensive discussion justifying the claim:

> 'Amacão' corresponds to `Ya/A Ma Gang' ('亞／阿 媽／馬 港') in Chinese, which serves as the origin of all kinds of geographical names in Portuguese that end with the nasal coda. (pg. 4)

So 'Macau' corresponds to Chinese Magang (妈港, "Mazu Harbor").